# Installed program won't show up in the Dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I have successfully installed doxygen with doxywizard via the Ubuntu Software Center as I can see in a terminal:

```
user@user-D3220-B1:~$ whereis doxywizard
doxywizard: /usr/bin/doxywizard /usr/bin/X11/doxywizard 
 /usr/share/man/man1/doxywizard.1.gz
```

Starting doxywizard from the terminal works fine, but if I type it in the Dash nothing is found. Instead it says:

```
Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search.
```

Why is that?

Comment: logout and login back.Then search again.

Comment: Still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. That's why it is so.

You can load a program by entering the following code + enter in terminal.

```
doxywizard
```

I suggest making manual shorcut for it, developers will hopefully fix that in future tho...

Source: [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/doxygen/+bug/569124)